# replace table by other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, overwrite

We have this current database which we need to replace some tables by anther tables from backup database. we are using sql server 2008 r2 and I want to know how to do overwrite or replace current tables by new table having same structures. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**step1:**

```
Restore the backup to the same server with a different name.
```

Say if your actual database is "MYDB", you can restore the backup and name "MYBD_BKUP" something like that.

```
You can restore database using SQL server management studio

Right click on Databases>Restore Database
```

**Step2**: `Once restore is success full, you can delete all the tables (to be deleted) from MYDB`

**Step3:**

```
transfer table from MYDB_BKUP

USE MYDB

select * into <table1> from MYDB_BKUP.dbo.<table1>

etc.. for each table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE MyTable;
    END
```

put this query in your backup database script, for each table you want to replace. like..

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchemaName' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'table_staff'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE table_staff;
END
```

Comment: thanks for replying ... but the situation like this ,Im not planing to replace all tables .. my database has more than 120 tables but it is only around 4 tables need to be replace. because I can not replace all since others tables has the organization information which the back up does not has.  I only want to replace certain tables example .. table_staff need to be replaced....

Comment: @MohammedAli As i said `put this query in your backup database script, for each table you want to replace.` you dont need to replace all tables just put the query for only those 4 tables you want to get from backup.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to replace the whole database with backup database then...

1. Right Click on Database to which u want to replace
2. Go to Task
3. Go to  Restore...
4. check from file radio button
5. Select backup file
6. Now your .bak file will show in lower area and check this file by clicking on checkbox
7. Select options of left side in popup
8. check checkbox.. override existing
9. click ok

This will replace your current database with backup database